# Is it possible to permit some users to see pills but not others with Drupal Bootstrap?

Tags: css, drupal, user-permissions, nav-pills

In a website I am working on, a customer wants another menu with multiple dropdowns under the main navigation menu.

Instead of using the typical menu features associated with Drupal's Bootstrap theme, I used pills.

Is it possible to enable some users to view these pills but not others? I know it is possible to do so with pages.

I have enabled each user to have their own page, which only they can see.

Ideally, I'd like for each user to be able to see a "My Profile" Pill (or Menu, or Button, whatever works), that directs them to their own page.

The problem I've been having is that in the pill drop-down menu, they can also see everyone else's link to their page, even though when they click it, they can't access another user's page.

Also, I have tried the same thing with the Main Navigation Menu that is already built into the Bootstrap theme, and it works just not with the pills.

I can't seem to find any code that references this either.

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question, so you will get a suitable answer. Read the docs on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific. What are those "Pills"? Menu items, menus, blocks?